# Why is this app crashing? I'm trying to play a short intro movie before the app is loaded

Tags: objective-c, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmoviewcontroller

In my app I have a short movie that I want to play before the the menu is loaded. I've written a few lines of code. The app works well but when I close it on the simulator or on my iPad Xcode reports me a crash. Do you have any idea why it is crashing?

#### Source

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {    
    NSString *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"videoplayback" 
                                                    ofType:@"mp4"];

    MPMoviePlayerViewController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:url]];


    [player view].frame = [viewvid bounds];
    [viewvid addSubview: [player view]];

    MPMoviePlayerController *playerv = [player moviePlayer];
    [playerv play];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:)                                                 
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:playerv];



    [super viewDidLoad];    
}

- (IBAction)nextView {
    scelta2 *second = [[scelta2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"scelta2" bundle:nil];
    second.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController:second animated:YES];
}

- (void) movieFinishedCallback:(NSNotification*) notification {
    MPMoviePlayerController *playerv = [notification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                  object:playerv];    
    [playerv autorelease];

    self.viewvid = nil;
    // dismiss your view or present a new view here.
    [self nextView];
}
```

#### Crash Report

```
Incident Identifier: DF27AF52-C96A-4F48-A06D-F8E587344C4B 
CrashReporter Key: 7e0569ccbea58bb19a7cc0569fc3db4e34af027d
Hardware Model: iPad1,1 
Process: video [1685]
Path: /var/mobile/Applications/CC8800CF-456A-46E9-B4E5-A43326CA7188/video.app/video   
Identifier: video
Version: ??? (???)
Code Type: ARM (Native) 
Parent Process: launchd [1]

Date/Time: 2011-06-26 12:24:50.109 +0200 
OS Version: iPhone OS 4.3.3 (8J3) 
Report Version: 104

Exception Type: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) 
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x6465634f 
Crashed Thread: 0

Thread 0 name: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread Thread 0 Crashed: 0 libobjc.A.dylib 0x34fc6c98 0x34fc4000 + 11416 1 MediaPlayer 0x308208b0 0x307d5000 + 309424 2 Foundation 0x34dd717c 0x34dc9000 + 57724 3 CoreFoundation 0x325bf208 0x32552000 + 446984 4 CoreFoundation 0x32559ee4 0x32552000 + 32484 5 Foundation 0x34dd45cc 0x34dc9000 + 46540 6 UIKit 0x321b3cfa 0x32149000 + 437498 7 UIKit 0x3214daf2 0x32149000 + 19186 8 UIKit 0x3214d20e 0x32149000 + 16910 9 UIKit 0x3214cc4c 0x32149000 + 15436 10 GraphicsServices 0x35425e70 0x35421000 + 20080 11 CoreFoundation 0x325c7a90 0x32552000 + 481936 12 CoreFoundation 0x325c9838 0x32552000 + 489528 13 CoreFoundation 0x325ca606 0x32552000 + 493062 14 CoreFoundation 0x3255aebc 0x32552000 + 36540 15 CoreFoundation 0x3255adc4 0x32552000 + 36292 16 GraphicsServices 0x35425418 0x35421000 + 17432 17 GraphicsServices 0x354254c4 0x35421000 + 17604 18 UIKit 0x32177d62 0x32149000 + 191842 19 UIKit 0x32175800 0x32149000 + 182272 20 video 0x000a1d4c 0xa0000 + 7500 21 video 0x000a1cf4 0xa0000 + 7412

Thread 1 name: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager Thread 1: 0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x32a7ffbc 0x32a6d000 + 77756 1 libdispatch.dylib 0x33253032 0x3324d000 + 24626 2 libdispatch.dylib 0x3325403a 0x3324d000 + 28730 3 libdispatch.dylib 0x332535ea 0x3324d000 + 26090 4 libsystem_c.dylib 0x35b7058a 0x35b3c000 + 214410 5 libsystem_c.dylib 0x35b70bbc 0x35b3c000 + 215996

Thread 2: 0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x32a7f3ec 0x32a6d000 + 74732 1 libsystem_c.dylib 0x35b706d8 0x35b3c000 + 214744 2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x35b70bbc 0x35b3c000 + 215996

Thread 3 name: WebThread Thread 3: 0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x32a7cc00 0x32a6d000 + 64512 1 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x32a7c758 0x32a6d000 + 63320 2 CoreFoundation 0x325c82b8 0x32552000 + 484024 3 CoreFoundation 0x325ca562 0x32552000 + 492898 4 CoreFoundation 0x3255aebc 0x32552000 + 36540 5 CoreFoundation 0x3255adc4 0x32552000 + 36292 6 WebCore 0x315f327e 0x315ed000 + 25214 7 libsystem_c.dylib 0x35b6f30a 0x35b3c000 + 209674 8 libsystem_c.dylib 0x35b70bb4 0x35b3c000 + 215988

Thread 4 name: com.apple.coremedia.player.async Thread 4: 0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x32a7ed18 0x32a6d000 + 72984 1 libsystem_c.dylib 0x35b96860 0x35b3c000 + 370784 2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x35b3deb2 0x35b3c000 + 7858 3 CoreMedia 0x3640f8f4 0x3640d000 + 10484 4 CoreMedia 0x3640f83a 0x3640d000 + 10298 5 MediaToolbox 0x312eaa64 0x312e7000 + 14948 6 CoreMedia 0x3642d4dc 0x3640d000 + 132316 7 libsystem_c.dylib 0x35b6f30a 0x35b3c000 + 209674 8 libsystem_c.dylib 0x35b70bb4 0x35b3c000 + 215988

Thread 5 name: com.apple.coremedia.player.async Thread 5: 0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x32a7ed18 0x32a6d000 + 72984 1 libsystem_c.dylib 0x35b96860 0x35b3c000 + 370784 2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x35b3deb2 0x35b3c000 + 7858 3 CoreMedia 0x3640f8f4 0x3640d000 + 10484 4 CoreMedia 0x3640f83a 0x3640d000 + 10298 5 MediaToolbox 0x312eaa64 0x312e7000 + 14948 6 CoreMedia 0x3642d4dc 0x3640d000 + 132316 7 libsystem_c.dylib 0x35b6f30a 0x35b3c000 + 209674 8 libsystem_c.dylib 0x35b70bb4 0x35b3c000 + 215988

Thread 6 name: com.apple.coremedia.player.remote Thread 6: 0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x32a7cc00 0x32a6d000 + 64512 1 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x32a7c758 0x32a6d000 + 63320 2 MediaToolbox 0x312ef9b4 0x312e7000 + 35252 3 CoreMedia 0x3642d4dc 0x3640d000 + 132316 4 libsystem_c.dylib 0x35b6f30a 0x35b3c000 + 209674 5 libsystem_c.dylib 0x35b70bb4 0x35b3c000 + 215988

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State: r0: 0x1dd7b050 r1: 0x308a9f86 r2: 0x1dd76b90 r3: 0x3e0971b4 r4: 0x64656347 r5: 0x308ba2ec r6: 0x00000005 r7: 0x2fe9d1dc r8: 0x00000000 r9: 0x3e097088 r10: 0x00000002 r11: 0x00000004 ip: 0x3e08af74 sp: 0x2fe9d1c4 lr: 0x308208b7 pc: 0x34fc6c98 cpsr: 0x200f0030

Binary Images: 0xa0000 - 0xa2fff +video armv7 <6456439d2af93cc2bab97d86162748e9> /var/mobile/Applications/CC8800CF-456A-46E9-B4E5-A43326CA7188/video.app/video 0x1fd9000 - 0x1fddfff AccessibilitySettingsLoader armv7 <977d3eb9b0a4389e85e0e8eb64806759> /System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/AccessibilitySettingsLoader.bundle/AccessibilitySettingsLoader 0x2fe9f000 - 0x2fec4fff dyld armv7 /usr/lib/dyld 0x300a3000 - 0x30390fff libLAPACK.dylib armv7 /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib 0x30395000 - 0x303a5fff AppleVXD390Framework armv7 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleVXD390Framework.framework/AppleVXD390Framework 0x303dd000 - 0x303e2fff liblaunch.dylib armv7 /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib 0x306f7000 - 0x306f8fff libsystem_network.dylib armv7 <39bf0f48bd8539169a77f8f61cdcd4c9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib 0x306fb000 - 0x30711fff EAP8021X armv7 <9fefc0ada30435fbb3b51818c74f6cb8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X 0x307d5000 - 0x308e7fff MediaPlayer armv7 /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer 0x309a3000 - 0x309a3fff libdnsinfo.dylib armv7 <21415179ffa03f949fa8cc851c6c31c7> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib 0x309b3000 - 0x309c0fff libbsm.0.dylib armv7 <0a1e2bb78d5138419ecad8ba0fe42fdd> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib 0x309c1000 - 0x309c2fff libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7 /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib 0x30a34000 - 0x30a76fff CoreAudio armv7 /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio 0x30b41000 - 0x30c6ffff AudioCodecs armv7 <7758e15bf4a33834afebc201e8ddabe0> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioCodecs 0x30c81000 - 0x30c90fff AppleVXD375Framework armv7 <6090475fa0453a02a9dae2fe3fc8ccde> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleVXD375Framework.framework/AppleVXD375Framework 0x30ca4000 - 0x30cb7fff libmis.dylib armv7 <529ea6e3a87230ce9f6cf3285c22429c> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib 0x30cb9000 - 0x30cc2fff MobileWiFi armv7 <03d98d5cf6383695aa7d8a88da52f410> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi 0x30d0e000 - 0x30d0efff Accelerate armv7 <7d5ad465049136afaa1f0d89aac600bc> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate 0x30d7a000 - 0x30d8cfff VoiceServices armv7 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VoiceServices.framework/VoiceServices 0x30da4000 - 0x30e4afff Celestial armv7 <407badafc6403692bf099d542d28bf7f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial 0x30e4b000 - 0x30ef4fff libxml2.2.dylib armv7 <5538d3f2c7d83b88b06168488fe6326b> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib 0x30ef5000 - 0x30f00fff libz.1.dylib armv7 /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib 0x31053000 - 0x31112fff CFNetwork armv7 /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork 0x31113000 - 0x31115fff libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7 /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib 0x31116000 - 0x31133fff libsystem_info.dylib armv7 <48016be86e3f3cd9aeee1c6590e1ac6f> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib 0x312e7000 - 0x31433fff MediaToolbox armv7 <482b13059e8a329fa5d832baede25103> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox 0x3143a000 - 0x3143efff libGFXShared.dylib armv7 /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib 0x3144d000 - 0x314acfff libBLAS.dylib armv7 <0b36b2272aa33a8c9aa22d99c89d7189> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib 0x31541000 - 0x31543fff CrashReporterSupport armv7 <9e7efa009730322f84bbc5d8bf1ded94> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport 0x3157b000 - 0x31589fff OpenGLES armv7 <5a76beaeaa013f0cbf16e5cb154598ab> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES 0x315e5000 - 0x315ecfff libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7 <0a082e1d475432959ba93aa3dbf7fb31> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib 0x315ed000 - 0x31bf8fff WebCore armv7 <07941e59d0a33f94802c16c76238fddf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore 0x31ced000 - 0x31d1cfff SystemConfiguration armv7 <1d73b8a159363f96bb9c039655c5eae6> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration 0x31d1d000 - 0x31d60fff ManagedConfiguration armv7 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration 0x31d95000 - 0x31d9ffff AccountSettings armv7 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings 0x31ebb000 - 0x31ebefff MediaRemote armv7 <0804293b2774359189f3a67e2c81558d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaRemote.framework/MediaRemote 0x31ee9000 - 0x31fd6fff libiconv.2.dylib armv7 /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib 0x31fe6000 - 0x31feafff libcache.dylib armv7 /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib 0x31feb000 - 0x31ff0fff MobileKeyBag armv7 <8c35c090bc373cb181fc26b961b8dba5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag 0x31ff1000 - 0x31ff1fff vecLib armv7 <0c60cd0a60f43d2791d36cb357d30e3c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib 0x3201c000 - 0x3201ffff libmacho.dylib armv7 <43311c113a9d3182b7d007129819f029> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib 0x32149000 - 0x324d6fff UIKit armv7 /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit 0x324d7000 - 0x324dafff IOSurface armv7 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface 0x32552000 - 0x32637fff CoreFoundation armv7 /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation 0x32683000 - 0x326c2fff libSystem.B.dylib armv7 <33dcf9a403ae3fd5971d6030ada2fcab> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib 0x326cc000 - 0x326cefff libAccessibility.dylib armv7 /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib 0x326cf000 - 0x3271dfff CoreMotion armv7 <5e6b884d36d93789b40b7f3876130417> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion 0x32722000 - 0x32724fff IOMobileFramebuffer armv7 <683f321680763e519d61541170ba2133> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer 0x3276b000 - 0x3281cfff WebKit armv7 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit 0x3287c000 - 0x3287dfff H264H4.videodecoder armv7 <868cffd60b2e389da329c34899a456d9> /System/Library/VideoDecoders/H264H4.videodecoder 0x3287e000 - 0x3299ffff CoreGraphics armv7 <65f6c8701b563542820a26b0dfc4f6a4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics 0x329a0000 - 0x329a3fff ApplePushService armv7 <015c68c15621348db9f6a012499170e1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService 0x329be000 - 0x329bffff MP4VH2.videodecoder armv7 /System/Library/VideoDecoders/MP4VH2.videodecoder 0x32a0e000 - 0x32a0efff libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7 /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib 0x32a17000 - 0x32a6cfff libvDSP.dylib armv7 <0221caba81a235c5a896a835e2aac047> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib 0x32a6d000 - 0x32a84fff libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7 /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x32a85000 - 0x32a8bfff ProtocolBuffer armv7 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer 0x32b00000 - 0x32bc6fff MusicLibrary armv7 <71a09022bd8b3b6a90a250199d190f10> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MusicLibrary.framework/MusicLibrary 0x32bc7000 - 0x32bc8fff libdyld.dylib armv7 <41a7b5e5d9983449ab33affed0f635ad> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib 0x32bd9000 - 0x32bdcfff ArtworkCache armv7 <4863e321afee3ac5a3749e50cd926597> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ArtworkCache.framework/ArtworkCache 0x32cd8000 - 0x32d0dfff AddressBook armv7 <3f2071a77bc134cd82065eef90d4082f> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook 0x32d0e000 - 0x32d20fff PersistentConnection armv7 <659ea9d5b13d3fefb37acff09016a69c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection 0x32d21000 - 0x32e3bfff libicucore.A.dylib armv7 /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib 0x32e4f000 - 0x32e51fff JPEGH1.videodecoder armv7 /System/Library/VideoDecoders/JPEGH1.videodecoder 0x32e5b000 - 0x32e63fff MobileBluetooth armv7 <63f11756c4aa3262b2317ff3b8e2a977> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileBluetooth.framework/MobileBluetooth 0x32f7c000 - 0x32fb8fff libGLImage.dylib armv7 <9d97699e44ee3651ba4ac37e5adec35b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib 0x330ca000 - 0x33139fff ProofReader armv7 <6d843c6aecdd37ae84baa40af8ad7e65> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader 0x3313a000 - 0x33143fff CoreVideo armv7 /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo 0x3324d000 - 0x3325afff libdispatch.dylib armv7 <9a0511ad5ebc3db898f1f49ed1a73d34> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib 0x33342000 - 0x33375fff AppSupport armv7 <0217468bd9f839229a47910b7816b3d5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport 0x34dc8000 - 0x34dc8fff libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7 <42d8aa2a31843a6e8bfff745644a7ba5> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib 0x34dc9000 - 0x34ee8fff Foundation armv7 <09ff368178c5321c9715b9c8d491d53f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation 0x34efe000 - 0x34f04fff liblockdown.dylib armv7 <14c89b7346433c1f8675f454531f6ca3> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib 0x34f9f000 - 0x34fc3fff MediaControl armv7 <1cfc7d79f554357ab59eb69f9efebf07> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaControl.framework/MediaControl 0x34fc4000 - 0x35088fff libobjc.A.dylib armv7 <6b51e76fde9f381bb7b3bc5badbfee3a> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib 0x35089000 - 0x350c1fff IOKit armv7 <80ae313ad69d3363935c88e51a11862d> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit 0x351f1000 - 0x351f7fff IAP armv7 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IAP.framework/IAP 0x351f8000 - 0x3520efff VCH263.videodecoder armv7 <14da61904a0e37b691f75575802a3f50> /System/Library/VideoDecoders/VCH263.videodecoder 0x3520f000 - 0x3522efff Bom armv7 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom 0x3535d000 - 0x35364fff libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7 <55f29184efcc3046bb833dd72a4487e1> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib 0x35383000 - 0x35386fff CaptiveNetwork armv7 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork 0x353f9000 - 0x35405fff SpringBoardServices armv7 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices 0x35421000 - 0x3542dfff GraphicsServices armv7 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices 0x35791000 - 0x35792fff H264H2.videodecoder armv7 <3c26494ccbfe3645b1a8a12abc750e18> /System/Library/VideoDecoders/H264H2.videodecoder 0x357eb000 - 0x357effff AssetsLibraryServices armv7 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices 0x357fe000 - 0x35848fff libstdc++.6.dylib armv7 /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib 0x358b7000 - 0x358ccfff libresolv.9.dylib armv7 /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib 0x359d8000 - 0x359e2fff ExternalAccessory armv7 /System/Library/Frameworks/ExternalAccessory.framework/ExternalAccessory 0x35a8c000 - 0x35b3bfff QuartzCore armv7 /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore 0x35b3c000 - 0x35bbdfff libsystem_c.dylib armv7 /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib 0x35c28000 - 0x35c29fff libremovefile.dylib armv7 /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib 0x35c31000 - 0x35c65fff VideoToolbox armv7 <570c63dc3a273a5a8c9072fd5567f5c1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox 0x35c8a000 - 0x35c93fff ITSync armv7 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ITSync.framework/ITSync 0x35e8d000 - 0x35e99fff HomeSharing armv7 <2df6957cdfea31aea12eebf27ca1691c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/HomeSharing.framework/HomeSharing 0x35e9a000 - 0x35e9ffff libnotify.dylib armv7 <9d7198e91de9386a9e5ea43608a66a57> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib 0x35ea6000 - 0x35eecfff CoreTelephony armv7 /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony 0x35ef4000 - 0x35f3afff CoreLocation armv7 <249b8af3dc503d11bf3711f0407c66d8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation 0x35f58000 - 0x35f90fff libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7 /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib 0x35f91000 - 0x35f92fff CoreSurface armv7 <7b83cd757da73e6e826693c29296d3fa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface 0x35faa000 - 0x3603ffff ImageIO armv7 /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO 0x3608a000 - 0x36091fff AggregateDictionary armv7 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary 0x36121000 - 0x3614afff MobileCoreServices armv7 <57fef84bdc17301d8bf53ba0fb967fe6> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices 0x3614b000 - 0x36199fff GMM armv7 <049361f664eb3f30b0d25cd56ffc1f0f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GMM.framework/GMM 0x3619a000 - 0x3629efff JavaScriptCore armv7 <61a94142e2d23dafa2964190dd46e9e3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore 0x3629f000 - 0x362d6fff Security armv7 <6599f42a910b3b31a0e1d98c883d61cb> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security 0x362ec000 - 0x362edfff MP4VH4.videodecoder armv7 /System/Library/VideoDecoders/MP4VH4.videodecoder 0x362f5000 - 0x3630efff libRIP.A.dylib armv7 <4825c3e392983aba947eca06555e4480> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib 0x36407000 - 0x3640cfff libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7 /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib 0x3640d000 - 0x3644dfff CoreMedia armv7 <8e0570582ba535bfa74f1f00eef64376> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia 0x36457000 - 0x36459fff MobileInstallation armv7 <94b6d6c5d9883175af26764567528127> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation 0x36481000 - 0x364b4fff StoreServices armv7 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices 0x364ba000 - 0x364bbfff DataMigration armv7 <42e9e87a4e0735c3837e27d4f2adcf55> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration 0x36534000 - 0x36585fff libsqlite3.dylib armv7 <8a41cc6a6d9332308bc415d27577fd24> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib 0x365e9000 - 0x3673dfff AudioToolbox armv7 <6619c8c13f8d328e923e797fa8d0df23> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox 0x36741000 - 0x36761fff PrintKit armv7 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit 0x36762000 - 0x36767fff libcopyfile.dylib armv7 /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib 0x367d6000 - 0x36813fff CoreText armv7 /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
```

Comment: Could you provide the crash lines that XCode reports? So we can make sure where to start searching for errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try removing [playerv autorelease];
and see if it works?

Comment: great answer mate! thank you very much! Why was it crashing? thanks again!

Comment: It was crashing because `playerv` was over-released. Read the [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html).